# RViz -- How to publish more than 1 point?

Tags: ros, lidar, rviz, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a point cloud in RViz and I want to publish all the points in my selection.  When I select a subset of the point cloud, I can see in RViz that I have a collection of points selected.  When I then click "Publish Point", nothing is published to the topic /clicked_point.  If I then click on a single point in my selected cluster, I will get a single point published to topic /clicked_point,  but I actually want a way to publish (or even just save) that entire collection of points that I selected.  This image shows the issue I'm having:
[http://imgur.com/gallery/Leb79](https://imgur.com/gallery/Leb79)

Can anyone walk me through how to do this?  I'm using RViz 1.12.4 and ultimately, I'm just trying to "manually" segment my point cloud and save my selection of points.   Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255656/rviz----how-to-publish-more-than-1-point?/) by [chambana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28837/chambana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) on 2017-02-27**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/99796/rviz-storing-point-cloud-selection/ This might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@huanxiner has a good lead there. try this tool :-)

To follow up a bit: `Publish Point` cannot do this. This is just a tool to publish a single point you click. All the tools in the toolbar are totally seperate and don't interact in any way, typically.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chambana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28837/chambana/) on 2017-03-02**:
Thank you for definitively answering this.  I'll try the tool mentioned above.

**Comment by [JohnMMeyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27912/johnmmeyer/) on 2017-03-22**:
Hello chambana,
I have the same question as you. I was wondering if you had any luck with the suggested tool?

Thanks,
John

**Comment by [chambana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28837/chambana/) on 2017-09-02**:
No, I didn't.  Were you able to find a good solution?